If $\phi_D$ is associated to $|D|$, then $\phi^*_DH \sim D$
This question has been asked here but there was no answer provided. I've sharpened the question using the facts that all hyperplanes of $\mathbb{P}^n$ are linearly equivalent and that the pullback of linearly equivalent divisors are linearly equivalent.
Now given a smooth projective variety $X$ and a divisor $D$ of $X$, let $\phi_D: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ be the morphism associated to the complete linear system $|D|$. For a hyperplane $H$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, why do we have $\phi^*_DH \sim D$?

By definition of $\phi_D$.

Let's set up the situation. The morphism $\phi_D:X\to\Bbb P^n$ is defined by choosing a basis $b_0,\cdots,b_n$ for $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))$ so that $\phi_D^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(1) = \mathcal{O}_X(D)$ and $\phi_D^*(s_i) = b_i$, where $s_0,\cdots,s_n$ are the standard coordinates on $\Bbb P^n$.
What this means is that for a hyperplane divisor $H=V(h)$ on $\Bbb P^n$ cut out by a nonzero $h$, the pullback of $H$ is cut out on $X$ by $\phi_D^*(s)$, which is a nonzero global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. But every nonzero global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ gives a divisor linearly equivalent to $D$, so there you go.
